# Twig: get element of an array by key within an if statement

Tags: if-statement, twig

I'd like to get the value of an element by key within an if statement.

**Example:**

works:

```
{{ example[5] }}
```

doesn't work:

```
{% if example2 is example[5] %} something ... {% endif %}
```

**Exception thrown:**

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of statement block" expected)

Thank you very much

Kind regards

Comment: What are you trying to do? To compare the two sides, use `==`. `is` is used for some special cases, like `null`, `defined` or `even`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of

```
{% if example2 is example[5] %} something ... {% endif %}
```

try changing 'is' to '=='

```
{% if example2 == example[5] %} something ... {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you should use the `attribute` function to get the object or array value. [This link](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) may help you

Comment: I upvoted because this solved my situation which had to do with locating a key within an array by the value of another array.  Others may be looking for a similar solution coming to this question.